# Apple MapKit: annotations not showing under blue dot (user location) marker on the map

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I'm using Mapkit to create an app where users can place a point marker (MKPointAnnotation) on the map.
The problem is: seems that annotations are not drawn when in the vicinity of the blue dot (user location indicator).

Here's my code snippet. In this snippet I simply place the point marker at the center of the map whenever the map is dragged around.
This works most of the time, unless when the blue dot is also in the middle of the map, in which the point marker does not get drawn on the map

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView = MKMapView(frame:self.view.frame)
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.mapType = .standard
    mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
    mapView.isScrollEnabled = true
    mapView.isRotateEnabled = true
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
    mapView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    mapView.mapType = MKMapType.satellite
    view.addSubview(mapView)
}

func mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
    updateLocationMarker(coordinate: mapView.centerCoordinate, showTitle: false)
}

func updateLocationMarker(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, showTitle: Bool) {
    if self.pointMarker != nil {
        mapView.removeAnnotation(pointMarker)
    }
    self.pointMarker = MKPointAnnotation()
    self.pointMarker.coordinate = coordinate
    self.pointMarker.title = stringFromCoordinate(coordinate: coordinate)
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(pointMarker)
}
```

It seems that the "blue dot" is a special type of MKAnnotation.
I've tried setting the display priority for the views, but they don't seem to do anything:

```
    let pointMarkerView = self.mapView.view(for: pointMarker)
    pointMarkerView?.displayPriority = .required
    let userLocationView = self.mapView.view(for: mapView.userLocation)
    userLocationView?.displayPriority = .defaultLow
```

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you don't mind the marker staying in the "center" of the map permanently, you could just anchor it as a UIView on top of the map view. Then just grab the location of the center of the map as needed which would be where the pin is "placed"

Comment: no, I'll do that as well. the marker staying in the center of the map in this snippet was just for the sake of brevity. In the full-fledged app, I want to be able to drop the marker, and then freely scroll the map. The problem is: if I dropped the marker on the blue dot, then the marker will not be drawn at all.

Comment: try turning .userTrackingMode to .none, does that change anything?